# How can i have media queries resize my email images for Samsung Galaxy S/Samsung Galaxy SII/Samsung Galaxy SIII

Tags: email, samsung-mobile

I am using Media queries to resize the images in email (width:100%) for mobile devices screen. It looks good in iphone ipad , but doesn't seem to resize in Samsung Galaxy/SI/SII/SIII Android . CAn anyone please let me know how could I resize my images to fit the screens of these devices.

Thanks,
Srishida